# Robot Pattern for Flutter Integration Tests

Tags: flutter, integration-testing

To make flutter integration tests easy to read I'm trying to use the robot pattern to write code like this (chaining):

```
test('home', () async {
  driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
  HomeRobot(driver)
    .seesFromPlacesField()
    .seesToPlacesField()
    .seesNotSwapButton();
});
```

The base robot class looks like this:

```
class RobotBase {
  RobotBase(this.driver, this.finder);

  final FlutterDriver driver;
  final SerializableFinder finder;

  sees(String valueKey) async {
    print("sees: $valueKey");
    await driver.waitFor(find.byValueKey(valueKey));
  }

  seesNot(String valueKey) async {
    print("sees not: $valueKey");
    await driver.waitForAbsent(find.byValueKey(valueKey));
  }
}
```

And an actual robot like this:

```
class HomeRobot extends Robot {
  HomeRobot(FlutterDriver driver)
      : super(driver, find.byValueKey(home_keys.page));

  Future<HomeRobot> seesFromPlacesField() async {
    await sees(home_keys.fromPlaceField);
    return this;
  }

  Future<HomeRobot> seesToPlacesField() async {
    await sees(home_keys.toPlaceField);
    return this;
  }

  Future<HomeRobot> seesNotSwapButton() async {
    await seesNot(home_keys.swapButton);
    return this;
  }

  Future<HomeRobot> seesSwapButton() async {
    await sees(home_keys.swapButton);
    return this;
  }
}
```

But a working test looks currently like this (thening):

```
test('home', () async {
  driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
  HomeRobot r = HomeRobot(driver);
  await r.seesFromPlacesField().then((r) async {
    await r.seesToPlacesField().then((r) async {
      await r.seesNotSwapButton();
    });
  });
});
```

Or this (awaiting):

```
test('home', () async {
  driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
  HomeRobot r = HomeRobot(driver);
  r = await (await (await r
      .seesFromPlacesField())
      .seesToPlacesField())
      .seesNotSwapButton();
});
```

Any ideas on how to chain this nicely?

**Solution**

The robots build up the 'work':

```
class HomeRobot extends Robot {
  HomeRobot(FlutterDriver driver, Future<void> work) : super(driver, work);

  HomeRobot seesFromPlacesField() {
    work = work.then((_) async => await seesKey(keys.homePageFromPlaceField));
    return this;
  }

  SearchRobot tapsOnFromPlacesField() {
    work = work.then((_) async => await tapsOnKey(keys.homePageFromPlaceField));
    return SearchRobot(driver, work);
  }

  // ...
}

class SearchRobot extends Robot {
  SearchRobot(FlutterDriver driver, Future<void> work) : super(driver, work);

  SearchRobot seesBackButton() {
    work = work.then((_) async => await seesTooltip(Robot.backButtonTooltip));
    return this;
  }

  HomeRobot tapsOnBackButton() {
    work = work.then((_) async => await tapsOnTooltip(Robot.backButtonTooltip));
    return HomeRobot(driver, work);
  }

  // ...
}
```

A base class provides all basic steps:

```
class Robot {
  Robot(this.driver, this.work);

  final FlutterDriver driver;

  Future<void> work;

  seesKey(String key) async {
    print("sees key: $key");
    await driver.waitFor(find.byValueKey(key));
  }

  tapsOnKey(String key) async {
    print("taps on key: $key");
    await driver.tap(find.byValueKey(key));
  }

  // ...
}
```

And a test case looks like this:

```
test('home', () async {
  HomeRobot robot = HomeRobot(driver, Future.value(null));
  await robot
      .seesFromPlacesField()
      .seesToPlacesField()
      .seesNotSwapButton()
      .tapsOnFromPlacesField()
      .seesSearchField()
      .seesBackButton()
      .tapsOnBackButton()
      .seesFromPlacesField()
      .work;
});
```

Comment: That pattern is useless in dart. You can directly use `..` operator to chain calls. No need to return this

Comment: The cascade operator doesn't work in that case because I have to await each future before I can move on to the next step. Also a future can return another robot e.g. when the HomeRobot taps on a DetailButton then a HomeDetailRobot with other possible UI options will be returned.

Comment: My bad then, forget it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attempted to adapt the API you want - however I added a second class in order to do so. The Robot in this case contains the actual async commands needed to interact with the driver. The corresponding "Work" class contains a Future which it gradually builds up as you call methods on it. These methods in turn call the actual async work on the Robot, however we can continue calling them without waiting for the robot to finish. At the end we return the final future which can be awaited for all of the work to be completed.

Note that we cannot use the `..` syntax in this case, since we need to call `await` on a value returned by the Work class.

```
 final driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
 final robot = HomeRobot(driver);
 await robot.start()
   .seesFromPlacesField()
   .seesToPlacesField()
   .seesNotSwapButton()
   .work();


class HomeRobot {
  HomeRobot(this.driver);
  final FlutterDriver driver;

  /// Create a new work class which builds up a Future.
  HomeRobotWork start() => new HomeRobotWork(this);

  Future<void> _seesFromPlacesField() async { ... }

  Future<void> _seesToPlacesField() async { ... }

  Future<void> _seesNotSwapButton() async { ... }
}

class HomeRobotWork {
  HomeRobotWork(this.robot);
  final HomeRobot robot;
  Future<void> _result = new Future.value(null);

  /// Add a future onto the result value
  void seesFromPlacesField() {
    _result = _result.then((_) => robot._seesFromPlacesField());
    return this;
  }

  void seesToPlacesField() {
    _result = _result.then((_) => robot._seesToPlacesField());
    return this;
  }

  void seesNotSwapButton() {
    _result = _result.then((_) => robot._seesNotSwapButton());
    return this;
  }

  Future<void> work() => _result;
}
```